# Adding name to last edited (google script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently i have the following google script:

```
   function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if(s.getName()=='Setup BRF'){
      if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
         var row = r.getRow();
         var time = new Date();
         time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "dd-MM-yy' , 'HH:mm:ss");
         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J1').setValue(time);
      };
    };
   };
```

Everytime i edit something on the sheet called Setup BRF it updates the time and date in J1 to show when it was last updated/edited.

My question is if its possible to add a name to lets cell K1 which shows who last updated this sheet. My skill with javascript is nihil so any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#about_authorization_protocols

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) passed to the function

So change the definition to

```
function onEdit(e) {
```

and then you can use `e.user` to get to the user

Something like this

```
if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow(),
        time = new Date(),
        user = e.user;

    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "dd-MM-yy' , 'HH:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J1').setValue(time);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K1').setValue(user);
};
```

Comment: Getting a type error on line 9 where i entered: var user = e.user();

Comment: Not `e.user()`, but `e.user`, as Gaby put it. However, you'll be disappointed anyway, since other users' identities won't be available to your `onEdit()` function anyway. ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser%28%29)) You'll get YOUR id when you edit the sheet, but a blank string when others do.